Excel formula to group rows to create groups with difference of 2 between values in one column
I have a dataset that looks like this:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Text1
Text1
Text1
189.21


Text2
Text2
Text2
180.20


Text3
Text3
Text3
236.67


Text4
Text4
Text4
204.23


Text5
Text5
Text5
205.21


Text6
Text6
Text6
209.20



The array is of variable length but fixed width.
I'm looking for a formula that can create groups (of 3 rows per group but if this could be adjustable that would be ideal) such that each group has no values in column D within 2 of each other.
So for the example above the 2 groups returned could be



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Text1
Text1
Text1
189.21


Text2
Text2
Text2
180.20


Text4
Text4
Text4
204.23



and



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Text3
Text3
Text3
236.67


Text5
Text5
Text5
205.21


Text6
Text6
Text6
209.20



If there are multiple ways to make a group it does not matter which way is chosen as long as no data is duplicated.

Are those two groups on different sheets, on the same sheet but side by side or one below the other with an empty row??? Each of these would have another solution.

How large is your dataset? Would you hope to be able to group the whole of it into sets of three?

The groups should be on the same sheet, one below the other, either with an empty row between each, or without and with a column containing group number.

The dataset has 51 rows (but if possible I would like to use the formula with datasets in the future which may have more or fewer rows), and I would hope to group the whole of it into sets of 3 yes.

Are you open to using VBA?  It's a simple exercise to write a bit of code to do this.

How is this a very easy problem to solve with VBA. I'm genually curious so please just go ahead and post an answer @FrankBall.

Fun question, but a difficult problem since there could be a fair number of values in D sitting within a distance of <=2 of eachother. We could brute-force this a bit using recursion:

Formula in F2:
=LET(_x,LAMBDA(_f,_r,_n,_l,LET(_s,ROUNDDOWN((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_r))-1)/_n+1,0),IF(OR(MAP(DROP(_r,,3),_s,LAMBDA(_v,_w,SUM((ABS(DROP(_r,,3)-_v)<=_l)*(_s=_w))))>1),_f(_f,SORTBY(_r,RANDARRAY(ROWS(_r))),_n,_l),HSTACK(_s,_r)))),_x(_x,A2:D7,2,2))

So what you get here is a recursion untill your initial array is sorted in such manner that there is no value within an absolute distance of 2 (I made this dynamic too). You basically call this function with this part:
_x(_x,A2:D7,3,2)

The 3rd parameter indicates your groupsize, whereas the last one is the limitation you want to give it.

Here is a result for: _x(_x,A2:D7,2,2)

Here is another result for: _x(_x,A2:D7,2,10)


Very nice. As far as I can see no brute force solution would scale to 51 rows and I can't see any obvious short cuts unless perhaps you knew something about the distribution of the data (and were a mathematician!) so as you say it is a difficult problem to solve generally.

Thanks @TomSharpe, and no I just figured that we just keep trying to jumble the data untill the distribution is ok :)

It might be a stupid newbie question, but what it this LAMBDA(Function, Parameters) syntax? how do you write that off-hand without any debugging tools?

Fair chance that is the result of me being too much of a nerd. It's basically a regular LAMBDA() function in overdrive where we keep calling the function in recursion untill the definition in IF() is satisfied a.k.a. a recursive lambda. I've never used debug tooling to be honest. What can you recommend? @rachel

Legend! I use https://github.com/microsoft/Excel-Labs/blob/main/advanced-formula-environment/README.md for intelliSense and easier inspection.

This solution worked best for me, thank you! The calculation was near instant for my 51 row dataset. I tried it on a ~4000 row set just for fun and it was a lot less instant

@AdamW, you are welcome. And yes, ~4000 rows means a lot more chances of invalid grouping thus causing respinning :)

I think you can first sort the data.
Then choose the smallest number, e.g 189.21, then get the next number that is greater or equal than 189.21 + 2 in your dataset, then get the next number that is greater or equal than next_number+2.. repeat the process until you reach your group_size.
You can write a recursive lambda called GetGroupData() to do that.
Once you get all the numbers that can be put in the same group with 189.21, you remove those numbers from your dataset. Call GetGroupData() on your remaining dataset, remove the numbers for the second group...repeat the process until there in no numbers left in your dataset.
You can write another recursive lambda called SplitData to do that.
Here is how I defined GetGroupData():

=IF(
    ROWS(row_indices) >= group_size,
    row_indices,
    LET(
        current_index, @TAKE(row_indices, -1),
        current_num, INDEX(sorted_data, current_index, 4),
        next_index, XMATCH(current_num + diff, INDEX(sorted_data, , 4), 1, 1),
        IF(
            ISNA(next_index),
            row_indices,
            GetGroupData(sorted_data, VSTACK(row_indices, next_index), group_size, diff)
        )
    )
)

Below is SplitData()

=LET(
    current_row_indices, TAKE(row_indices, , -1),
    IF(
        ROWS(current_row_indices) >= ROWS(sorted_data),
        groups,
        LET(
            remaining, ISNA(XMATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(sorted_data)), current_row_indices)),
            remaining_sorted_data, FILTER(sorted_data, remaining, ""),
            next_row_indices, GetGroupData(remaining_sorted_data, {1}, group_size, diff),
            next_group, CHOOSEROWS(remaining_sorted_data, next_row_indices),
            SplitData(
                remaining_sorted_data,
                HSTACK(row_indices, next_row_indices),
                VSTACK(groups, EXPAND("", 1, 4, ""), next_group),
                group_size,
                diff
            )
        )
    )
)

The result:
=LET(
    group_size, 3,
    diff, 2,
    row_indices, GetGroupData(SortedData, {1}, group_size, diff),
    groups, CHOOSEROWS(SortedData, row_indices),
    SplitData(SortedData, row_indices, groups, group_size, diff)
)



I'm not sure about your logic to be honest. It seems to work by chance on the given dataset. Let's simplify a list of values and apply this: [1,3,5,6,8,9]. You would now group [1,3,5] but that would leave [6,8,9] being invalid. This is only on a set of 6 numbers, but imagine the trouble you'd have to go through with 51. Simply put, you'd always have to make sure that all the remaining numbers do have the ability to create a valid set before you start making these sets. Either way, thought you may want to get some positive criticism. +1 from me anyways.

@JvdV, for [1,3,5,6,8,9], my intention is to group it into [1,3,5]; [6,8]; [9]. But if we need to split them into groups of same size, my solution won't work.

That's how I read the question. It wouldn't matter which lines get grouped as long as none of the values are within an absolute distance of <2. In this little example we could create say [1,5,8] and [3,6,9].

I couldn't help engaging my mathematician friend for this :)
If the number of values in the data set is divisible by the group size, and there is at least one solution with the distance requirement, following will give a solution:

Sort the values in ascending order
Select each element in the row to be interleaved with elements from the next group, because they will be at least the required distance apart.

Here's how the indices will look for the 51 elements:

So, applying this:
=LET(
    data, SORT(A1:D6, 4),
    num_rows, ROWS(data),
    num_cols, 3,
    indices_for_result, TOCOL(WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(num_rows), num_rows / num_cols)),
    result, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            SEQUENCE(num_rows),
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                VSTACK(
                    acc,
                    IF(
                        MOD(cur, num_cols) = 0,
                        EXPAND(CHOOSEROWS(data, INDEX(indices_for_result, cur)), 2, , ""),
                        CHOOSEROWS(data, INDEX(indices_for_result, cur))
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        1
    ),
    result
)



Looks very interesting, im going to give this a try and test later today.

Thank you @JvdV, I appreciate it very much!

Did some testing but I don't think it does what you think it should be doing here either unfortunately. It's the same issue as with other concepts I believe, you can't make a set if you are not 100% sure you can make a valid set with the remainder. For example. Change these numbers in the 4th column to [1,2,2,6,8,9] or put some small decimal numbers behind them. The grouping is wrong. Sadly I'm no mathematician so can't point to where the conceptual approach goes wrong.

Thanks @JvdV, this method works only if there's a solution; it won't otherwise. Is there a solution with this set?

ahhh like that! No there shouldn't be a solution there. That makes sense though. I think this is pretty clever :). The only thing I still notice is that on a set where you have say 5 rows it wouldn't work. I assume your solution relies on a n-fold of the size of the grouping? Meaning if each grouping needs to be 3, your data needs to be a multiple of 3?

Yes, that how I interpret the question. I've tried to improve the explanation - please let me know if it needs be clarified further. Thanks again!
